# Fixing Python dependency mess

Tags: apt, package-management, python, pip, raspberrypi

On a Raspberry Pi I installed some python software, a part with pip, and other parts with apt-get. So I am now in a situation, where there are some packaged waiting to be installed that assume python 3.5 and others 2.7 and somehow this lead to some sort of deadlock I see no way out.

Whatever software I touch with apt-get now I am presented with these errors:

```
Setting up python-crypto (2.6.1-7) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
`enter code here`    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-crypto (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

How can I fix this?

apt-get clean, autoclean, purge do nothing because said software does not exist in armhf (which is why I tried to install it with pip).
`pip uninstall` doesn't do anything because it somehow thinks the libraries weren't installed at all.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~> sudo apt-get install python-wheel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-wheel is already the newest version (0.29.0-2).
python-wheel set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Setting up python-crypto (2.6.1-7) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-crypto (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-wheel (0.29.0-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-wheel (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-gi (3.22.0-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-gi (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-dbus (1.2.4-1) ...
Remove stale byte-compiled files...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-dbus (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-pip (9.0.1-2+rpt2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pip (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-secretstorage:
 python-secretstorage depends on python-dbus; however:
  Package python-dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-secretstorage (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-keyring:
 python-keyring depends on python-dbus; however:
  Package python-dbus is not configured yet.
 python-keyring depends on python-secretstorage; however:
  Package python-secretstorage is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-keyring (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-crypto
 python-wheel
 python-gi
 python-dbus
 python-pip
 python-secretstorage
 python-keyring
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to link my system python back to python2.7.
Apparently I changed it to python3.5, which caused this error.